# "Like Box" plugin is not showing stream if "data-show-faces" is set to false

Tags: stream, facebook-likebox

We have "Like Box" plugin on one of our websites, configured to show only live stream from our facebook page. It was working perfectly fine until 3 to 5 days ago. Now it shows the stream only when "data-show-faces" is set to true, otherwise it does not. Is this a bug introduced by new changes at Facebook developers, or is this as expected?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding data-height="300" (or your appropriate value). You can verify this at the developers.facebook page by setting the height attribute.